# Berliner for the people

Tags: techniques

For those who have made one, please describe your most successful attempt at producing a nice tart traditional Berliner. Please include ingredients, but most importantly, process in your response. Prost.

Comment: What books and websites did you check? What recipes have you tried? What happened? What results were you looking for specifically?

Comment: I've not attempted one yet. I've read a smattering of sources on the subject. I get the feeling that sour mash is the most successful approach, but wanted to hear from people here who have experience.

Comment: mod note: there's a couple of close votes on this, but I'm going to opt to leave it open. Berliner is a style that does have particular, objective, processes to produce, and it's hard for me to dismiss those as "too broad" or "subjective".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few ways to get to a Berliner Weiße:

1. [Sour mash](http://seancoates.com/blogs/berliner-weisse): introduce lactobacillus to the mash, hold around 120°F (and ideally anaerobically) for 2-3 days to sour. Boil and ferment normally and neutrally.
2. Kettle sour: perform the mash, introduce lacto to the wort, hold at temp, boil and ferment.
3. Lactic acid sour: introduce lactic acid either to the kettle or post-fermentation.
4. Lactobacillus fermentation: use a lactobacillus culture either in primary fermentation or post-primary.

A benefit to pre-fermentation souring is that any lactobacillus culture is killed by the boil, and thus won't impact "cold-side" equipment. A drawback is that early souring can drop the pH low enough to interfere with fermentation (though I haven't experienced this, even with wort pH down to 3.3).

A downside to "natural" mash/kettle souring is the process difficulty of keeping a volume of mash or wort in a temperature range for multiple days.

A downside to "natural" mash/kettle souring is the possibility for other bacterial infections or mold to take hold.

A downside to lactobacillus fermentation is very long fermentation timeframes.

I've had success in years past with a sour mash in a normal insulated cooler mash-tun, with boiling-water infusions twice a day. The temp ranges all over the place, but generally stays in a reasonable range for lacto. Purging the headspace of the cooler with CO₂ also helps promote lacto, instead of other things.

This past year I had success [transferring the mash into a corny, which I submersed into a water bath inside my keggle, and used a RIMS tube to maintain the water bath temperature](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLj5H4lXQWcBacAk5GhuH7PZ8sHFg8FOP8) (and thus the mash temperature). As a side effect, I could purge the corny headspace with CO₂ through the input port.

In both scenarios, I've fermented with 1056/US-05 without issue in a normal timeframe. Also, in both scenarios I added a couple of reserved cups of the dry, crushed grain to the ~120°F mash as the source of the lactobacillus.

Ingredients: 75% pilsner, 25% wheat. 9-15 IBU neutral hops (Liberty).

See also this [2000 BYO article about sour mashing](http://byo.com/stories/item/889-how-to-make-a-sour-mash-techniques).